# How to convert a SQL query output (dataframe) into an array list of key value pairs in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created a dataframe in spark scala shell for SFPD incidents. I queried the data for Category count and the result is a datafame. I want to plot this data into a graph using Wisp. Here is my dataframe,

```js
+--------------+--------+
|      Category|catcount|
+--------------+--------+
| LARCENY/THEFT|  362266|
|OTHER OFFENSES|  257197|
|  NON-CRIMINAL|  189857|
|       ASSAULT|  157529|
| VEHICLE THEFT|  109733|
| DRUG/NARCOTIC|  108712|
|     VANDALISM|   91782|
|      WARRANTS|   85837|
|      BURGLARY|   75398|
|SUSPICIOUS OCC|   64452|
+--------------+--------+
```

I want to convert this dataframe into an arraylist of key value pairs. So I want result like this with (String,Int) type,

```js
(LARCENY/THEFT,362266)
(OTHER OFFENSES,257197)
(NON-CRIMINAL,189857)
(ASSAULT,157529)
(VEHICLE THEFT,109733)
(DRUG/NARCOTIC,108712)
(VANDALISM,91782)
(WARRANTS,85837)
(BURGLARY,75398)
(SUSPICIOUS OCC,64452)
```

I tried converting this dataframe (t) into an RDD as `val rddt = t.rdd`. And then used flatMapValues,

```
rddt.flatMapValues(x=>x).collect()
```

but still couldn't get the required result.

Or is there a way to directly give the dataframe output into Wisp?

Comment: can you update your question with what you have tried ?

Comment: @eliasah I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pyspark it'd be as below. Scala will be quite similar.

Creating test data

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,1), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"])
```

Mapping the test data, reformatting from a RDD of Rows to an RDD of tuples. Then, using collect to extract all the tuples as a list.

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).collect()
```

> [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 20), (3, 18), (3, 18), (3, 18)]

Here's the [Scala Spark Row documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html) that should help you convert this to Scala Spark code

Comment: I have tried this in scala. This is my command `t.rdd.map(x=>(x(0),x(1))).collect()` and got result as key value pairs of Array[(Any, Any)]. How can I get the same with Array[(String,Int)].

Comment: Got it using `t.rdd.map(x=>(x(0).toString,x.getInt(1))).collect()`. Thanks for your help.